# Find label address in MIPS according to this table

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

How can I find the address of the label `reversed` in this table

[image: Text Segment]

I know I need to use the basic column.

Comment: Or you can turn on "Show Labels Window (symbol table)" in the Settings menu.